# How to manually set which storyboard view to show in app delegate

Tags: ios, ipad, uiview, uistoryboard

I have an app that wants to log out user whenever application is inactive for a set period of time.  It's multiple different views in the app, and i want the app delegate to set loginview as current view whenever this method fires:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

How to manually set loginViewController as current showing view in the storyboard in this method?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                                             bundle: nil];
LoginViewController *loginViewController = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];
[_window setRootViewController:loginViewController];
```